# How to determine if TD has only text and next TD contains control that starts with specific ID

Tags: jquery

Im not a JQuery expert and need some help.

I have a form that I'm trying to determine if a `TD` cell has only text (literal control) and the next `TD` has a control that contains an `id` that starts with "UI".  This is supposed to happen when the user hovers over the literal text.

Example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:Literal ID="LSomeID" runat="server"></asp:Literal></td>
        <td><asp:DropDownList ID="UISomeID" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm trying to display a tooltip when the user hovers the literal.  When they do need to look at next `TD` and grab the id if it starts with "UI" and then do a database lookup.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you.  No it should only return id of next td if hover of TD with literal has only text.  If i understand your questions correctly

Comment: `literal` converted to span. you can find this with `$("table tr span")`

Comment: When I look at the source it shows <td>some text</td>.  How can i be sure there are not other elements or controls and just text?  Thank you

Comment: Thank you all for your great help.  Im working on a combination of the helpful code presented.  I will post the final results when done.  Thank you again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**JS Fiddle** - *updated*](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/2zwvs4rb/)

**Code:** - *updated*

```js
var $tds = $('#tbl td'), 
    pattern = '3'; // the pattern we'll search for.

$tds.each(function(){
 var $th = $(this),
    $children = $th.children(),
   $content = $th.text();
    
      // if the content exists and it is text
      // check for the existance of the pattern
     if($content && $children.length == 0){
      if($content.indexOf(pattern) != -1){
      
       var $next = $th.next(),
         $thisID, $nextID;
     
        // add classes to the current and next TD's
       $th.addClass('contains');
        $next.addClass('next');
        
        // get ID's of the current and the next TD's
        // if the current TD is the last one in its TR
        // then return "no next".
        $thisID = $th.attr('id');
        $nextID = $next.attr('id') ? $next.attr('id') : 'No next';
        console.log('ThisID: ' + $thisID);
        console.log('NextID: ' + $nextID);
     } 
      console.log('----------------');
    }
});
```

```css
table#tbl td{ border:1px solid black; }
.contains{ background-color:orange; outline:2px navy solid; }
.next{ background-color:green; color:white; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl">
  <tr>
    <td id="1-1">item 1.1</td>
    <td id="1-2">item 1.2</td>
    <td id="1-3" id="3.1">item 1.3</td>
    <td id="1-4">item 1.4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="2-1">item 2.1</td>
    <td id="2-2">item 2.2</td>
    <td id="2-4">item 2.3</td>
    <td id="2-5">item 2.4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="3-1"></td>
    <td id="3-2">item 3.2</td>
    <td id="3-3">item 3.4</td>
    <td id="3-.4">
      <p>item 3.5</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
<p> Note that the first td in the third tr wasn't selected because it is empty</p>
<p> also note that item 3.5 in td4 tr3 wasn't selected because it doesn't contain 
  text only it has a p tag wrapping the text</p>
```

Comment: Thank you.  This may work if I can replace this if ($content.match('3')) to determine if cell only contain text.  I will not know specifically what each literal will contain

Comment: let me make a working example to check if the content is text only

Comment: @ches185 now it is working, checking if the td is not empty, also if it has text only

Answer (score 2):

Tooltip:

```
<div style="position: absolute; border: 1px solid black; display: none" id="tooltip">
  Tooltip
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function ()
{
  $('td').filter(function ()
  {
    var contents = $(this).contents();
    return contents.length == 1 && contents[0].nodeType == 3;
  }).mouseover(function ()
  {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $control = $this.next().find(':first-child');
    if ($control.attr('id').indexOf('UI') == 0)
    {
      var offset = $control.offset();
      $('#tooltip').css({
        top: offset.top + 'px',
        left: (offset.left + $control.width()) + 'px'
      }).show();
    }
  }).mouseout(function (e)
  {
    $('#tooltip').hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: This looks like a great solution but i have like a 100 forms and cant go through all of them and add that class to do td's.  Is there a way to determine if its a literal control and add that class on the fly or if TD contains only text and nothing else.  Thank you again

Answer (score 2):

Some conditional logic is all that is needed

```
$('td').hover(function() {
    var $cell = $(this),
        $next = $cell.next(),
        $prev = $cell.prev();
    // if no tags as children it is text only
    if (!$cell.children().length) {
        // see if neighbors have wanted ID
        if ($next.find('[id^="UI"]').length || $prev.find('[id^="UI"]').length) {
            //show tooltip
        }
    }

}, function() {
    //hide tooltip
});
```

Or conversely if you are needing to use a plugin on those cells you can use `filter()`

```
$('td').filter(function() {
    var $cell = $(this),
        $next = $cell.next(),
        $prev = $cell.prev(),
        hasChildren = $cell.children().length;

        return !hasChildren && ($next.find('[id^="UI"]').length || $prev.find('[id^="UI"]').length);


}).mytoolTipPlugin();
```

Alternatively here's a way to do it using the known ID's:

```
$('td:has(select[id^="UI"])').each(function(){
   var $cell= $(this), $prev = $cell.prev(), $next=$cell.next();
   if(!$prev.children().length){
        $prev.mytoolTip()
   }
   if(!$next.children().length){
        $next.mytoolTip()
   }       
});
```

Comment: wasn't clear what `next` meant so I looked in both directions. In DOM terms `next` is always the following element

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this, hope it will add some value.

```
  $('table tr').hover(function(){

      var literal  = $(this).find('td:first');

      // check if literal has text and id start with UI of next td to litral is not undefiend(means it exist), also check if first td just contains string not sub elements.

    if(literal.children().length < 0 && literal.text().length > 0 && literal.next(td[id^="UI") != undefiend){

    //make ajax call or db look up

   }
```

Comment: Thank you.  Will this text() eliminate other elements and controls if they exist in that td?

Comment: Updated code to check if first td just contains string not sub elements using literal.children().length < 0